# How to change a key in gltf file?

Tags: three.js, gltf

I want to change this key value 0.5 on

```
 "baseColorFactor" : [
                    0.004314713645726442,
                    0.42002472281455994,
                    0,
                    0.5
                ],
```

This is the complete object

```
"materials" : [
    {
        "alphaMode" : "BLEND",
        "doubleSided" : true,
        "emissiveFactor" : [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "name" : "dgray",
        "pbrMetallicRoughness" : {
            "baseColorFactor" : [
                0.004314713645726442,
                0.42002472281455994,
                0,
                0.5
            ],
            "metallicFactor" : 0,
            "roughnessFactor" : 0.5
        }
    },
    {
        "alphaMode" : "BLEND",
        "doubleSided" : true,
        "emissiveFactor" : [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "name" : "Material.004",
        "pbrMetallicRoughness" : {
            "baseColorFactor" : [
                0.034654635936021805,
                0.29569298028945923,
                0,
                0.5
            ],
            "metallicFactor" : 0,
            "roughnessFactor" : 0.5
        }
    }
],
```

i tried `materials[0].pbrMetallicRoughness.baseColorFactor[3] =  1;` but doesnt work,
that is from gltf file. i want the gltf to change transparency when the user clicks on it.

This is the code:

```
const domEvents = new THREEx.domEvents(camera, renderer.domElement);
domEvents.addEventListener(obj, 'click', event => {
    materials[0].pbrMetallicRoughness.baseColorFactor[3] = 1;
});
```

Comment: Hi, are you loading this glTF file into a particular WebGL framework, like ThreeJS or Babylon?  What does the loading code look like?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, im using ThreeJS for this. The code is below  'const domEvents = new THREEx.domEvents(camera, renderer.domElement);
        domEvents.addEventListener(obj, 'click', event => {
            materials[0].pbrMetallicRoughness.baseColorFactor[3] =  1;
                
        });
'

Comment: I think a big part of the problem is that after ThreeJS loads a glTF model, the materials aren't glTF materials anymore, they're converted to ThreeJS materials during loading.  So you have to get a reference to the new materials, and make adjustments there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply again, can you tell me how to do that please or an example?

Comment: I doubt it'll help a lot, but you can do this without threejs, by just parsing the gltf as json and then changing the key...

Comment: hmmm, thats a good idea, thanks i will search how to do that as im a new coder only.